# CORS Header Missing on Angular Resource Requests Only

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I have a working node/express backend running on localhost. I'm building a project application that needs to fetch data from goodreads api. When I execute the request, I get:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: 
The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at 
https://www.goodreads.com/book/title.json?author=Arthur+Conan+Doyle&key=[my_key]&title=Hound+of+the+Baskervilles. 
(Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).1 <unknown>
```

Server side, everything is working correctly. I have enabled CORS, and when I check the headers, 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is available on everything coming from my server after checking the header in Firefox and Chrome dev tools. When I make a request via $resource, however, 'Allow-Access...' is not present in my header. Here is the code for the resource:

```
.factory('goodReads', function($resource) {
    return $resource('https://www.goodreads.com/book/title.json');
})
.controller('AddBookSelectorController', function($resource, goodReads) {
    this.fetch = function() {
        var key = '[my_key]';
        var data = goodReads.query({author: 'Arthur Conan Doyle', key: key, title: 'Hound of the Baskervilles'});
        console.log(data);
    };
});
```

I'm calling fetch via ng-click, and everything executes fine except I get the CORS error. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I am new to angular, and my suspicion is there is a problem with my resource request or something in configuration, but I can't seem to find an answer to fix my problem in the documentation or other stackoverflow questions.

**Update 3:** It is not a localhost issue. I tried pushing it to my domain and using a simple button which ran an xhr request to the OpenBooks api, and the problem got worse. It is hosted via Openshift, and now the 'Allow-Control-Access-x' headers are gone even for other files on my server. Really beginning to bang my head against the wall here. I am removing the Angular tags, because it has nothing to do with Angular.

**UPDATE 2:** I got it working after installing 'Allow-Control-Allow-Origin' extension in Chrome. Has my problem been the fact that I'm running this on localhost? Or is there something else going on? The header is still not being set without the extension.

**UPDATE:** I've been working on this since 8am, and still no luck. I have tried rewriting the request using Angular's $http and also with Javascript's xhr following the example from [HTML5 Rocks | Using Cors](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) and I'm still having the same problem with each method. Like I said, the necessary header information is available from files on my server, but it breaks when I make requests to other sites.

I'm starting to think this might not be an Angular problem, but I really have no clue. Just to be safe, here is the code I added to Express to enable CORS, including app.use so you can get an idea for where I called it:

```
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Content-Length");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    next();
});
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
```

**Edit: Here are the headers from the API request:**

Request Headers

```
Host: www.goodreads.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101     Firefox/40.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive
```

Response Headers

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 686
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 02 Sep 2015 17:20:35 GMT
Etag: "a2be782f32638d2a435bbeaf4b01274a-gzip"
Server: Server
Set-Cookie: csid=BAhJIhg1MzgtNTk4NjMzNy0wNzQ4MTM5BjoGRVQ%3D--afed14b563e5a6eb7b3fa9005de3010474230702; path=/; expires=Sun, 02 Sep 2035 17:20:33 -0000
locale=en; path=/
_session_id2=fd45336b8ef86010d46c7d73adb5f004; path=/; expires=Wed, 02 Sep 2015 23:20:35 -0000; HttpOnly
Status: 200 OK
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff, nosniff
X-Frame-Options: ALLOWALL
X-Request-Id: 1K8EJWG30GWDE4MZ4R5K
X-Runtime: 2.277972
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

**Headers for the .js file from my server:**

Request

```
Host: localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101   Firefox/40.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.1924088292.1439681064; connect.sid=s%3AB4O0Up9WF5iqkfky__I0XCiBD2aMATlq.gbJUC9GseqnJvRTEIbcwxD6cwFQeL7ljNScURCJ5As0
Connection: keep-alive
If-Modified-Since: Wed, 02 Sep 2015 17:08:40 GMT
If-None-Match: W/"886-14f8f0828c1"
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

Response:

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Wed, 02 Sep 2015 17:20:30 GMT
Etag: W/"886-14f8f0828c1"
Last-Modified: Wed, 02 Sep 2015 17:08:40 GMT
X-Powered-By: Express
access-control-allow-headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
```

Comment: Can you post the headers from your API request?

Comment: Thanks for looking at it, Fred. I added the header info per your request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this problem exposed my ignorance, but maybe this will help other newbies to CORs like me. I finally figured out the problem after getting a copy of ***CORs in Action*** and working through the first example using the Flickr API.

My problem had nothing to do with the backend, Angular, jQuery's .ajax method, or xhr. All of my requests were properly formatted. **The problem was the APIs I attempted to use did not have CORs enabled on their server.** O.o As soon as I changed the data type to jsonp, everything went through.

Anyway, for you newbs out there like me, here are some pointers to help you if you run into this problem:

**1. Don't assume the API you are using has CORs enabled**

I don't know why, but I blindly picked two APIs that don't have CORs enabled, which is what caused all the fuss for me. I have never run into this problem before because the work I have done with APIs have always been from big companies like Flickr that had CORs enabled. If they don't set Access-Control-Allow-Origin on their server, you can request them to enable it and use JSONP in the meantime.

If the API has an option for a callback at the end, that's a good sign you should use JSONP for your request. JSONP works by wrapping your request in a callback and exploiting a feature of the script tag. Scripts can pull other scripts from any domain, so it works as a hack to get the data. Here's a good link that helped me. [Exactly What is JSONP? | CameronSpear.com](https://cameronspear.com/blog/exactly-what-is-jsonp/)

**2. Check The Response Headers**

I got tricked by this, but remember that the response header on your request to an external API is the response from **their** server, not yours. It doesn't matter if CORs is enabled on your server, you are making the request to someone else, and the browser automatically sends your information to them in the request header. Remember, all of this checking is done by the browser for security reasons, so its doing the heavy lifting for you on the request side based on your ajax call. If Access-Control-Whatever doesn't show up in the response header, they don't have CORs enabled. If you are working on the frontend and requesting someone else's data, you can't do anything about it. Use JSONP and your problems will disappear (probably).

This whole fiasco for me started because I was confusing responses coming from my server with responses coming for their server. I correctly enabled CORs on my own server, but I was thinking it wasn't attaching the origin information to the request header which is why it was absent in the response header. In reality, everything was working correctly, but the API server didn't have it enabled.

So a day spent, but many lessons learned. Hopefully my wasted time helps someone else with their CORs problems. Note that my issue was stack agnostic, so regardless of how you are making your request, checking the response header is the first course of action to take if you run into a problem with CORs. After that, I would suggest looking into the request itself for errors.

Check out that book above or this link from the same author for more help, especially when it comes to non-simple requests [HTML5 Rocks | Using CORs](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/).